# Swift extend UInt8 Array

Tags: arrays, swift, uint8array

I wanted to extend an array of UInt8 values so I wrote this code in *Swift 3*:

```
extension Array where Element: UInt8  {

}
```

But I got this error:

**Type 'Self.Generator.Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'UInt8'**

So how do I fix it?

Comment: Take a look at `Data` in Swift 3. It's based on `UInt8` and conforms to `Sequence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `Element: X` means you want to inpose a type constraint on `Element` that is defined by `X`, where `X` must be a protocol or a class from which `Element` is derived. As a workaround if you'd like to construct an extension to `Array` which is only available to arrays with (value type) element `UInt8`, you could define a protocol to which only `UInt8` conforms, and use this protocol as a type constraint in the extension. E.g.

```
protocol MyType {}
extension UInt8: MyType {}

extension Array where Element: MyType  {
    // ...
}
```

At its current implementation, any code within the extension knows nothing more about the `Element` type than what is blueprinted in the `MyType` protocol (i.e., currently, nothing). Depending on what you want to achieve with your extension, you could add blueprints to `MyType` that you know are already fulfilled by implementations available to `UInt8`, e.g. some initializer. But a more sensible approach is to make use of the fact that `UInt8` conforms to the useful protocols `UnsignedInteger`, `Equatable` and `Comparable`. By using protocol composition, all methods blueprinted by these protocols can be readily available to `Element`:s in the extension, however restricting these elements to type conforming to your own protocol `MyType` (i.e., only `UInt8`):

```
protocol MyType {}
extension UInt8: MyType {}

extension Array where Element: MyType & UnsignedInteger {
    mutating func superfluouslyReplaceAllElements(with value: Element) {
        self = self.map { $0.advanced(by: $0.distance(to: value)) }
    } /* using 'advanced(by:)' and 'distance(to:)' methods of
         'Element', blueprinted in 'UnsignedInteger', to which 
         'Element' conforms */

    mutating func elementsSquaredWithOverflow() -> Bool {
        var overflow = false
        self = self.map {
            let result = Element.multiplyWithOverflow($0, $0)
            overflow = overflow || result.overflow
            return result.0
        }
        return overflow // did at least one element cause an arithmetic overflow?
    }
}

var foo: [UInt8] = [14, 87, 13, 240]
print(foo.elementsSquaredWithOverflow()) // true (at least one arithmetic overflow)
print(foo) // [196, 145, 169, 0]

foo.superfluouslyReplaceAllElements(with: 42)
print(foo) // 42, 42, 42, 42

var bar: [UInt16] = [14, 87, 13, 240]
bar.superfluouslyReplaceAllElements(with: 42)
    /* error: type 'UInt16' does not conform to protocol 'MyType' 
       OK, as expected!                                           */
```

This is just a short lesson in protocols and type constraints, however; if you intend to work with `UInt8` sequences in the context of bytes, follow @vadian:s advice in his comment to your question.

Comment: why do i have to re-invent the wheel for UInt64?  lazy Apple mofos.  can't use vectors of UINT64 or 32 without having to reinvent arrays and/or range.  i think you should have put SignedInteger in the protocol.

Comment: @μολὼν.λαβέ Once Swift 3.1 is released (currently available in Xcode 8.3+ beta), you will be able to extend generic types for concrete type requirements, e.g. `extension Array where Element == UInt8 { ... }` in which case we wont need the "dummy" protocol `MyType` above. I don't follow your discussion regarding re-inventing `UInt64` or `UInt32`, but possible this new feature will simplify this for you. If you have some concrete suggestions as how to improve Swift and Swift std library, you could try discussing it on the [Swift Evolution mail list](https://apple.github.io/swift-evolution/).

Comment: Ok, i will post my rant about how UInt is treated like a 3rd class citizen.