# Swift Extension for [UInt8]

Tags: swift

This is similar to a question that has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703928/swift-extend-uint8-array).

However in the comments of the answer to that question, there is the suggestion that from Swift 3.1 it should be possible to extend for specific types using the *Array where* syntax.

I'm trying to use *Array where* to make an extension for converting my byte arrays to Ascii strings like this:

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {

public static func ToAsciiString() -> String {
    if let result = String(bytes: self, encoding: .ascii) {
        return result
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Something more appropriate like throwing an error?
        return "ERROR"
    }
}
}
```

However this produces two compiler errors with the following messages:

> Initializer 'init(bytes:encoding:)' requires the types 'Array<UInt8>.Type.Element' and 'UInt8' be equivalent
>
> Type 'Array<UInt8>.Type' cannot conform to 'Sequence'

Is it possible to do what i'm trying to do?  If so can someone point out where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Remove `static`? is that a typo?

Comment: More of a copy/paste fail than a typo - it started life as a static method in a helper class before i tried to modify it into an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just looking to do something like this:

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {
    public func toAsciiString() -> String? {
        String(bytes: self, encoding: .ascii)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let arr: [UInt8] = [97, 98, 99]
if let str = arr.toAsciiString() {
    print(str)
} else {
    print("Error!")
}
```

> Prints:
>
> ```
> abc
> ```

The problem was that you marked the function as `static` - meaning that there is no `self` for the current instance. Removing this `static` works.

In terms of error handling: you could do something like throwing an error, but since only *one* 'error' can occur, I just decided that optionals is sufficient. The caller can then decide what to do if the result is `nil`.